# Why are there only three independent rotations and three independent boosts?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, inertial-frames, group-theory, lie-algebra

In what sense, there are *only* three independent rotations (i.e., rotations $R_x, R_y$, and $R_z$ about $x$, $y$, and $z$ axes, respectively)? Is it because *any* infinitesimal rotation about an arbitrary axis can be written as a sum of three rotations $R_x, R_y$, and $R_z$?

But then, in what sense, there are *only* three independent Lorentz boosts i.e., boost along x, y, and z-directions? Is it correct to say that a boost in an arbitrary direction can be decomposed into three independent boosts? I am not sure. Because there is no Lie group structure for boosts alone. In that case, how is the boost along x, y, and z-directions, enough to specify any arbitrary boost?

I would prefer a physical answer.

Answer (score 10):

When people talk about "number of independent rotations" or "number of independent boosts", what they mean is "the number of real-valued parameters you need to specify to uniquely determine a rotation or boost." Intuitively, one needs to specify two angles (longitude and latitude) to pick out an axis of rotation, and then a third angle to say by how much one should rotate about this axis. Similarly, I think it's intuitively obvious that one can perform any boost by specifying the magnitude and direction of the velocity corresponding to that boost, and a velocity vector has three components.

Here are some more details.

> Is it because any infinitesimal rotation about an arbitrary axis can be written as a sum of three rotations ,, and

Correct, an infinitesimal rotation about an arbitrary axis can be viewed as a superposition of rotations about $x$, $y$, and $z$.

A version of this statement for non-infintesimal rotations are that an arbitrary rotation can be decomposed into three rotations using [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles).

> Because there is no Lie group structure for boosts alone. In that case, how is the boost along x, y, and z-directions, enough to specify any arbitrary boost?

You are correct; a sequence of two non-collinear Lorentz boosts does not produce a pure Lorentz boost, but a boost plus a rotation, called a Wigner rotation.

Now, on the one hand, this is certainly strange and physically significant. For example, a sequence of non-collinear Lorentz boosts that returns an observer to their original rest frame may lead to a net rotation, called the Thomas precession, which appears in the fine structure of the Hydrogen atom.

On the other hand, in terms of counting parameters needed to specify a boost, the fact that two Lorentz boosts combine to give a Lorentz boost and a rotation is just a technical annoyance. The resulting boost is still defined in terms of three parameters, corresponding to the three parameters of velocity. Since rotations and boosts form a group (the Lorentz group), this is what you would generically expect -- combining two group elements (in this case two Lorentz boosts) gives you a generic group element, and for the Lorentz group a generic group element can be written as a product of a boost and a rotation.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to look at this is that rotations are not specified around axes, but within bivectors.

In three dimensions, there are three basis bivectors, canonically $xy$, $yz$, and $zx$, and infinitesimal rotations can be described by how much the $x$ component of a vector is shifted towards being a $y$ component, the $y$ component is shifted to being in the $z$ direction, and the $z$ component is shifted to being in the $x$ direction.

[It’s a special property of three-dimensional rotations that each bivector has a unique normal vector, so we can get away with saying that an $xy$ rotation is “around the $z$ axis”. For any other dimensionality, rotations must be specified using bivectors.]

In four dimensions, there are six basis bivectors (you can think of them as corresponding to the independent faces on a tesseract). In 3+1 space, three of the basis bivectors ($xy$, $yz$, and $zx$) involve only spatial axes, and so generalized rotations in those bivectors correspond to physical rotations. The other three generalized rotations ($tx$, $ty$, and $tz$) mix time and spatial information, and become boosts.